# link inside array or different link for window.location

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, canvas

I am using this pyramid chart. https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/pyramid-chart/
can the array be clickable? For example the array is like this

```
$dataPoints = array (
    array ("label" => "www.google.com", "y" => 8531),
    array ("label" => "www.yahoo.com", "y" => 4550),
    array ("label" => "www.facebook.com", "y" => 4395)
    )
```

This is what i have tried.. i need to have a different link each line i click. but this window.location only do is every time i click in any position it goes to the same link

```
window.onload = function () {
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
     animationEnabled: true,
     title: {
       text: "Order Fulfillment"
     },
       data: [{
   click: function (e) {
         window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
   },
         type: "pyramid",
         indexLabel: "{label} - {y}",
         yValueFormatString: "#,##0",
         dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
                                                }]
  });
    chart.render();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an function in your array. Your data points should look like this.

```
label: // your label
y: // your y
click: function(e){ window.location = "www.google.com"}
```

[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/90udxy5L/)